# Possible to publish app to specific app stores?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I was wondering, is it possible to publish an app to specific app stores, like ones where I know the ads will be targeted towards them? Or is there a way to set something in my app to do certain features for users in certain countries?

Comment: this is SO - it is not a webpage meant to replace ALL the documentation of ANY platform/technical topic in the world -> in this case, the iTunes Connect Developer Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In iTunesConnect when creating a new App, after the first couple pages there an option at the bottom to "specific stores". Click on this and select only the store you want the app to be available in.